# Connect SSH as SOCKS proxy using HTTP proxy

Tags: networking, ssh, proxy, http

I want to connect `ssh` with http proxy. It is because I can't directly connect to my server.
but I can connect to the http proxy. I see that `-o` command argument with **ProxyCommand** might be able to do this.
Can you give me an example to use -o? for example, the http  proxy is myhost.com port 80.

```
ssh -v -o {the configuration I want. maybe contains myhost:80} -p 443 myname@myserver
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to download `corkscrew` on your local client

```
$ ssh -o ProxyCommand='corkscrew proxyserver proxyport sshserver sshport’ user@sshserver
```

Comment: Thank you, this is definitely what I want. Thank you, once again.